# Space between characters gets deleted after clicking outside field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've added a space after 4 characters using JavaScript and changed the maxlength of the field from 6 to 7, but after going to the next field (or clicking anywhere outside the field), the space gets deleted.

It concerns the "Postcode" field on this [page](https://www.taxivacatures.nl/vacatures/chauffeur-leerlingenvervoer/)

How can I stop that from happening?

Code:

```
var input = document.querySelector(".input_postcode");

input.onkeydown = function() {
  if (input.value.length > 0) {
    if (input.value.length % 4 === 0) {
      input.value += " ";
    }
  }
};

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(".input_postcode").attr('maxlength', '7');
});
```

Comment: This element has got a `change` event handler added to it by Gravity Forms, that performs `this.value = this.value.replace(/\s/g, "").toUpperCase()` - so spaces in the value are explicitly getting removed at this point. Guess you'll have to go and check with GF, whether that is configurable / easy to disable.

Comment: Ah, missed this comment. Thanks, that explains a lot. I'll contact their support and get back to you when I got an answer.

Comment: I found the piece of code in the plugin and added the space between "", which worked. Thank you so much!

One last question: What's the code which I can use in custom JavaScript to prevent it from being overwritten by futire plugin updates?

Comment: You would probably have to try and remove the existing event handler using JavaScript, and then add your own instead.